# TYPO3 doNotLinkIt with hashtag

Tags: typoscript, typo3-7.6.x

I would like to know that the first navigation level does not perform any action.

The following TypoScript worked under TYPO3 v6.2:

```
lib.mainMenu = HMENU
lib.mainMenu {
  special = directory
  special.value = 1
  1 = TMENU
  1 {
    expAll = 1
    NO.allWrap = <li>|</li>
    NO.ATagParams = class="lvl1"

    ACT = 1
    ACT.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="active">|</li>
    ACT.ATagParams = class="lvl1"    

    IFSUB = 1
    IFSUB.doNotLinkIt = 1
    IFSUB.before = <a href="#" class="lvl1 no-link">
    IFSUB.after = </a>
    IFSUB.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="dropdown">|</li>

    wrap = <ul class="nav">|</ul>
  }
}
```

Now I've upgraded to TYPO3 v7.6, and the link is actively taking action. I always go to www.domain.com/#

How do I do that under TYPO3 v7.6?

Comment: Have you considered the dataProcessing?  That way you can do whatever you want by getting the navigation menu as an object and manipulate it how ever you want on a template. TypoScript is not necessary anymore. https://github.com/AKaravas/foundation_zurb_framework/blob/master/Documentation/ForAdminstrators/Navigation/Index.rst

Comment: Ahhh I just saw you re using TYPO3 v7. I don’t think that my solution would work on TYPO3 7. Correct me someone if I am wrong.